# CSS : z-index failed to make popup container?

Tags: css, firefox

i got this css stylesheet code

```
#nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: none;
    top: 42px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px 6px 10px;
    z-index: 10000;
    border: 1px solid #C0ACB2;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-bottom-color: #AF9DA3;
    border-top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.97;
}

#nav li:hover ul,
#nav li.iehover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

i want to make every #nav to be hidden and then displayed when cursor hover around it. But the problem is everytime is show, it's overlapped by other div. it's seem z-index is not working to make the #nav li ul becoming the front container.

i'm testing it in firefox and flock.

Comment: Indent all code with four spaces. This is not an answer, just a tip for when writing questions.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos : is this an answer ? i don't undersatnd it.

Comment: r u using nested lists ? if not then I think ul and li should be interchanged

Comment: yes, i use nested list. just like old navigation breadcrums

Comment: Every #nav? Is that means you've got more than one element with **nav** id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post up some HTML to go with that? Maybe the mistake is in your markup. Also, try using `display:none;` and `display:block;` instead of visibility. uls and lis are by definition block elements, but for hovering, this should work.

Comment: @kyle: thank you for the offer. i have answer this by myself. it's because i use overflow:hidden in it's parent container. ;)